# Capital Letters from 1700

Tags: nouns, british-english, capitalization, early-modern-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capitalisation of nouns in English (historically)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10522/capitalisation-of-nouns-in-english-historically)

After reading a recipe from 1747, I noticed that all of the nouns are capitalized. Is that a normal thing for that era? It's when things like "Fresh Butter" is in capitals that I started to wonder.

Comment: There’s a lot of hip-shooting to wade past, but there are also some real answers [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/29691/What-is-the-History-of-English-Capitalization).

Comment: English orthography in 1747 was a much closer sibling to German than it is today.

Answer (score 0):

I searched Google Books for ["fresh butter"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Fresh%20Butter%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22Fresh%20Butter%22&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1740,cd_max:31/12/1750&tbm=bks&ei=2uxMUInDN8Ke0QXhgYGQDA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=3b003db65f44374e&biw=1379&bih=886) (it's not case-sensitive), and got 20 results, of which 8 had the word "Butter" capitalised (but only one of them also capitalised "Fresh"). I think at least a couple of the citations were duplicates.

On that basis, I'd say OP's example wasn't *abnormal*, but it wasn't "the norm" either.

---

The full story of how standard capitalisation evolved/reduced several hundred years ago is discussed (sometimes cogently) in [tchrist's link](http://ask.metafilter.com/29691/What-is-the-History-of-English-Capitalization) above. A key point made by user:[holgate](http://www.metafilter.com/user/419) there is...

> The Change didn't occur at once, by some top-down Decree, but happened over a long period of Time, and according to Fashion. Regular Nouns go from Capitalised to lower-case; emphasised Nouns go from *Italicised-capitalised* to *italicised* or roman lower-case, depending on House Stile. Certain proper Nouns go from ꜱᴍᴀʟʟ ᴄᴀᴘꜱ to Capitalised.

I've no reason to doubt "holgate" is correct in saying *David Foxon's **Pope and the Early Eighteenth-Century Book Trade** is the canonical Work on this Topic.*

Comment: There's still uncertainty about capitalisation. On some public notices in the UK it seems quite random.

Comment: @Barrie England: Well, I suppose the government has better things to do than pass laws setting out national standards for capitalisation of Public Notices. Individual "style guides" may be adopted, but to be honest I think it would be more trouble than it's worth trying to get every public body to agree a standard guide and implement it consistently. Anyway, I like my music and movie files to have "Title Capitalised" names, and I'm never sure myself whether to capitalise some of the short words. I'm glad [foobar](http://www.foobar2000.org/) does it for me on music - movies can be tricky.