# Is capitalizing "master" and other honorifics appropriate?

Tags: capitalization

In BDSM relationships, a dominant male is often referred by his submissive counterpart as a "master", "sir" or by some other honorific. Some in the BDSM lifestyle insist that words referring to the dominant person in a relationship should always be capitalized, whereas those referring to the submissive partner should be written in lower case. While such a generalization does not adhere to the rules of the English language, I can't help but think that there are situations where capitalization is appropriate.

In particular, I am wondering whether capitalization of "master" is appropriate in the following examples, where the word refers to a specific person:

*"Welcome home, **Master**."*

*"No, **Master**, I haven't finished my chores yet."*

*"My **Master** will be with you shortly."*

I believe that the capitalization in the first two examples is correct, but not in the third. However, I am not certain about which rules apply and I'd appreciate it if somebody could shed more light on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

Capitalization (especially of titles) is a tricky business in English.  There is no hard-and-fast rule about capitalization.  In fact, many of the major style guides disagree on exactly what should or shouldn't be capitalized.  However, I'll give some general guidelines and let you make up your own mind:

### Titles in direct address

In all major style guides, when a title is used as a name in direct address of that individual, it is capitalized.  For example:  "That was very kind of you Mom."  "I love you Dad." "Stop being so good to me, Master." "So, I have to have surgery, Doctor?"

### Titles used in direct reference

When referring to a specific individual with their title, the title should be capitalized.  For example:  "I was excited when President Barrack Obama walked in the room."  "My favorite comic book character is Mr. Tony Stark."  "It took a while, but we finally got in to see Doctor John Smith."

However, (somewhat less commonly) some prefer that occupational titles not be capitalized, unless abbreviated.  For example, "Dr. John Smith" and "doctor John Smith".

### Titles used in indirect reference

Most style guides prefer titles used in reference to be lowercase.  For example, "I love my mother."  "The president gave a great speech." "My doctor did a great job with my surgery."

However, some titles are exempted from this.  *God* (when referring to the Judeo-Christian god) is always capitalized.  *The King* and *the Queen* are often capitalized. (For example, "The Queen has quite a way with words.")  When referring to a specific office, there is disagreement about what should or should not be capitalized.  Chicago and Wikipedia prefer "the president of the United States", while NY Times prefers "the President of the United States".  However, everyone prefers "King of France" to "king of France".

Comment: Re. your last paragraph, maybe that's because there are many doctors in the world, but there's only one Queen, one God, etc. (so those are a bit like proper nouns).

Comment: @ChrisW Actually, there are lots of queens, lots of kings, lots of gods, etc.  However, by convention, those titles get to be capitalized.

Comment: Maybe not: because if you were talking about the queen of Holland, for example, then you might say that, "the queen has a way with words" ... whereas, if you say "the Queen", I think that probably implies you're talking about, specifically, Her Britannic Majesty. Similarly there is only [one King of France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_king_is_dead,_long_live_the_king!#Origin).

Comment: @ChrisW I think you're assuming heck of a lot of context when you say "the Queen" means the Queen of the Commonwealth.  For example, "I just visited Holland.  It was such a great place.  And the Queen is such a nice woman!"  However, you would also see "I just visited Doctor Jim's office.  It was such a great place.  And the doctor is such a nice man!"  Again, these aren't hard and fast rules.  Historically, royalty and religious titles were always capitalized, and some style guides preserve that today, some don't.

Comment: Again in your example, there is only one of her. To be honest I wouldn't mind seeing "the Doctor" or "the Professor" or "the Major" either, especially if I knew who you were talking about. See also, [By the 17th century, the practice had extended to titles etc.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10602/9548)

Comment: @ChrisW There is also only one doctor (Dr. Jim) at Dr. Jim's office.  I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what a 'direct reference' is versus an 'indirect reference', i.e. the difference between "I was excited when President Barrack Obama walked in the room." versus "The president gave a great speech." They seem to me to be both references, and I'd capitalize them depending on whether we know who's being talked about: e.g. "My doctor (you don't know her) did a great job with my surgery" versus "The Doctor (you and I both know her) will see you now".

Comment: Perhaps my terms are unclear.  In the case of a direct reference, I mean that you are directly referring to a specific individual by name, and also using their title.  By indirect reference, I mean that you are indirectly referring to a specific individual only by their title.  An indirect reference may not be ambiguous, but it may also not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer may be simpler than any given. In the world of BDSM, it is your Master or Mistress who determines all your rules of capitalization, not the grammar books. (Using the male gender for simplicity), he may want you to capitalize He and You when writing to Him. He may want you to write Master with a capital no matter what the context, and he may want you to use the word "Master" at the end of any phrase, not just the end of a sentence. When you have a Master, you do exactly as he/He/she/She tells you. 
Secondly, when addressing a person who is or has been at the status of Master, if you have been at the (lower) status of a pet, servant or slave, you must address that individual as "sir" or "madame," ending all comments with "sir" or "madam" unless they tell you otherwise. If he tells you to capitalize "Sir" (or "Madame"), then you must. In short, then, this is less a grammar question and more a question that the world of BDSM answers.

Comment: How does this post answer the question?

Comment: The context of the question is exclusively about the rules of capitalization in a BDSM milieau. The answer keeps within the precise context of the question. Please tell me me how my post does *not* answer the question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The rule is that titles should be capitalised when used with the person's name or as a direct address, and not capitalized when used generally.

Comment: The 'rule' is not universally observed for the direct address. Twelve of the 46 citations for *Yes D/doctor* have a lower case **d** for *D/doctor*.