# Should I use "the queen" or "the Queen"?

Tags: capitalization

I know to capitalize a title when used with the name, i.e. Prince John, and not if it is general - "any prince will do." But if Queen Eleanor has been identified and I write as "the queen" in the same paragraph obviously referring to Eleanor, is it capitalized? The same would work for all church and nobility titles I presume.

Comment: What do British newspapers do when they refer to the Queen? That's where I'd start.

Comment: Related: [Is capitalizing “master” and other honorifics appropriate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207354)

Comment: Ultimately, this is a question of style; there is no single right or wrong answer. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, observe the guidance of an appropriate [style manual](/a/2579).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it seems it's up to you.  According to [GrammarBook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/capital.asp):

> Capitalize titles when they are used before names, unless the title is followed by a comma. Do not capitalize the title if it is used after a name or instead of a name.

However, they add a note that:

> Out of respect, some writers and publishers choose to capitalize the highest ranks in government, royalty, religion, etc.
>
> Examples:
>   *The President arrived.*
>   *The Queen spoke.*
>   *The Pope decreed.*
>
> Many American writers believe this to be a wrongheaded policy in a country where, theoretically, all humans are perceived as equal.

So, basically, it's your choice.  I don't think anyone will fault you either way.

Answer (score 1):

> A noun (when not at the start of a sentence) should be capitalised if and only if it is a **proper noun**, [which refers to a **specific** person, place, thing or idea without taking a limiting modifier.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proper%20noun)

Examples:

> - *"The Queen (of England) visited my school."*
>     Since the word "Queen" is capitalised here, we know that it must be referring to a *specific* queen. The words "of *x* country" do not have to be included.

---

> - *"She dreamed that one day, she would be the queen."*
>     In this sentence, the word "queen" is not capitalised as it does not refer to a specific person.