# HP Lovecraft's "A Reminiscence of Dr. Samuel Johnson" - Seemingly random capitalization in a sentence

Tags: capitalization

Mr. Lovecraft writes, "indeed, 'tis frequently by means of such Recollections that the obscure occurrences of History, and the lesser Anecdotes of the Greats, are transmitted to Posterity."

Why would he capitalize "Recollections," "History," "Anecdotes," "Greats," and "Posterity"?

Reading through the story, I have observed that he capitalizes words that otherwise should not be capitalized--at least to my amateur-level knowledge.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalisation of nouns in English in the 17th and 18th centuries](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10522) (the story you reference is not from the 17th or 18th century, but it is deliberately written in an archaic style)

Comment: Having read further into the story, I realized why Mr. Lovecraft capitalized the letters, answering my own question.

Thank you, semelic, for taking the time to respond.